# How to switch between fragments through a navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, material-design

I have a very basic question related to navigation drawer.
I have made an app that has a navigation drawer, but i have no idea how to change the view on selection of an item in nav drawer, however i can display a toast on every click, that means the issue is in switching the fragments during runtime.

**This is my main code:**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView; 
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

String TITLES[] = {"Home","Search","Recent Logs","My Wallet","Settings","Logout"};
int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.ic_action,R.drawable.ic_action_search,R.drawable.ic_action_logs,
        R.drawable.ic_action_wallet,R.drawable.ic_action_settings,R.drawable.ic_action_logout};
String NAME = "Akash Bangad";
String EMAIL = "akash.bangad@android4devs.com";
int PROFILE = R.drawable.default_user;
Toolbar toolbar;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
DrawerLayout Drawer;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,EMAIL,PROFILE);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    //Detect Gestures
    final GestureDetector mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

        @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

    });
    //Listen for clicks on navigation drawer
    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(),motionEvent.getY());
            if(child!=null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent) && recyclerView.getChildPosition(child)>0){
                Drawer.closeDrawers();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,TITLES[recyclerView.getChildPosition(child)-1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                selectItem(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child)-1);
                Fragment fragment;
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); // For AppCompat use getSupportFragmentManager
                switch(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child)) {
                    default:
                    case 1:
                        fragment = new ProfileInfoFragment();
                        break;
                }
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.mainLayout, fragment)
                        .commit();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        }
    });

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer,R.string.closeDrawer){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }
    };
    Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

public void selectItem(int i) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(TITLES[i]);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    else if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar">
    </include>
</LinearLayout>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Now i have created a simple fragment and i want the app to switch over to that fragment when clicked on an item in Navigation Drawer. Currently i am replacing mainLayout with my fragment but that is giving me ClassCastException.

```
Process: com.pocketcash.pocketcash, PID: 2456
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.pocketcash.pocketcash.MainActivity@c08ff73
        at com.pocketcash.pocketcash.ProfileInfoFragment.onAttach(ProfileInfoFragment.java:31)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:853)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Try switching to getSupportFragmentManager() . Also please post your error.

Comment: Don't use `LinearLayout`. Try it with `FrameLayout`

Comment: As i mentioned i am getting a ClassCastException when trying to switch the mainLayout with my fragment. I am not sure if that's the correct way to do it in the navigation drawer so i want you to guide on what should i add in my code to switch fragments during runtime.

Comment: You're using `ActionBarActivity` which is from AppCompat... there is something in your code that tells you what you're doing wrong. Can you find it? hint: ( // For AppCompat use getSupportFragmentManager)

Comment: @Yugesh  i tried that too but it didnt work either

Comment: @JaiSaxena Post Java Code with what are all the thing you `imported`

Comment: post your stacktrace also

Comment: @PedroOliveira i replaced ActionBarActivity with Activity but then i wasnt able to add my custom toolbar as the setSupportActionBar(toolbar); command gave an error

Comment: try this 
http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/recycler-view-handling-onitemtouch-for.html

Comment: Ahahah. You're not suposed to change your activity. You're suposed to change the `getFragmentManager()`.. Where did you copy pasted this code?

Comment: and it is recommended to use frameLayout when you deal with fragments

Comment: Can you paste your stacktrace? If you are getting ClassCastExepction check if you implemented the FragmentListener on your activity.

Comment: @PedroOliveira can you pls pinpoint the mistake, i watched various tutorials (around 5-6) on Navigation Drawer, and none of them showed how to handle fragment switches in the end. The code is a mix of all of them.

Comment: Friend, seriously. The commentary explicitly says "// For AppCompat use getSupportFragmentManager". What more can I say? You realize that you need to read and create code, not copy paste it. Replace `getFragmentManager` with `getSupportFragmentManager`. I don't know what more can I say.... You have it right in front of your eyes...

Comment: @PedroOliveira replacing it gives an error. Required android.app.FragmentManager
Found android.support.v4.ap.FragmentManager

I replaced the imported class.

Comment: @JaiSaxena you need to change your imports.. I suggest you read the documentation http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Friend you don't even know how to change imports... Don't you think you're asking too much of us?

Comment: @PedroOliveira friend, see my edited comment.

Comment: what is R.id.mainLayout ?, i can't see it in your activity_main layout

Comment: `Required android.app.FragmentManager Found android.support.v4.ap.FragmentManager`....... it's `app`... not `ap`..... o.O

Comment: @AndroidWeblineindia mainLayout is id of LinearLayout in activity_main.xml 
pedro, yes that was just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ActionBarActivity`, you should use classes from the support library: `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` and `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of default ones.

So you have to replace `getFragmentManager()` with the `getSupportFragmentManager()` and `import android.app.Fragment;` with `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`.

Go through this document [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)

Comment: switch(recyclerView.getChildPosition(child)) {
                        default:
                        case 1:
                            fragment = new ProfileInfoFragment();
                            break;
                    }

is there any change in this part too? new ProfileInfoFragment is incompatible with fragment

Comment: @JaiSaxena In your Fragment class did you extend the `android.app.Fragment` or `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` this.

Comment: the program did run successfully but on selecting the nav drawer item i got ClassCastException again

Comment: @JaiSaxena okay.Then why you not post the adapter class coding.Post that one.